# How related publish works?

Tags: content-editor, publishing

Recently our client content author was trying to do the below steps and am not sure if the problems are actual problems or that's how SC related publish should work?

Heres what our Content Author is trying to do.

1. Upload image to the media library
2. Create a new hero slide (data) > add new image & title > Save.
3. Create a new hero slider (module) > add the newly created hero slide item (from step 1) > Save.
4. ON any page, I change home hero slider in presentation details to the new hero slider module (step 2)  > Save
5. Go to publish, preview > No image appears  **this is problem #1**

I have both checkboxes checked for related items and subitems > The related items do not get published.
i.e. if I publish my page then I would assume that it will publish the image which I had uploaded and the slider's slide (step 1) which I used on the page. 
But my image does not get published.
**This is problem #2**

We are on SC 8.1 Update 3, with load-balanced CDs, Mongo and SOLR.

This question is different then below  [What does the "Publish related items" checkbox do in Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/what-does-the-publish-related-items-checkbox-do-in-sitecore)

It is different because 
A) I am not sure why the image won't appear in preview mode? If I click edit mode then only I can see the image in experience editor.
B) Even if I see the image in edit mode and I try to save and publish it doesn't show me the image in the Experience Editor preview mode or in the cd sites.
C) It could be a configuration issue or it could be the false expectation from CA. AS they are uploading an image first then they are creating a slide and using that image in a slide. And that slide is being used on a page's module. So not sure if publishing a page can take care of Hero slider, hero slide and its newly uploaded image. 
d) If I upload the image directly while creating slide it works as expected. i.e. I create a new slide and then upload image using media field on the slide item and then I use that slide on page's hero slider and save page I can see image in the edit and preview mode of Experience Editor and on upon publishing I can see the image on the CD and CM sites as well.

I hope that helps.

Thanks
Mrunal

Comment: @mark Cassidy, i tried explaining how it is different, hope that helps.

Comment: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/image-not-published-in-data-source-item-sitecore-8-1

Comment: I was in doubt as to which of these 2 to select as "duplicate". It's either one or the other.

Comment: @MarkCassidy you are correct i am reading this http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/image-not-published-in-data-source-item-sitecore-8-1 and this is close to what i want so i think you can close my question.

Comment: Mrunal, as it stands, this question is unlikely to gain much more attention, so I recommend that you allow this question to remain closed and post a new question phrased similar to the following: "Publish related items does not appear to be working. I have the following reproduction steps ... This seems wrong to me becasue ... I am expecting ... to happen. What can I do to fix this or am I misunderstanding something?" Your question will likely get more attention and better answers if you do this. Be sure to mind the formatting and use bulleted/numbered lists when possible. Everyone likes dots.