# Add an item to another items related items programatically

Tags: link-database, related-items

I have a page with a wysiwyg editor that allows users to select images from the media library and inserts them into their content and save as a sitecore item.

The problem is that these images aren't published as they're not part of the related items.

I was hoping there's a field that just takes the guids of any related items but it looks like it's all done in the link database. I see a `GetItemReferences` but no `CreateItemReferences` or similar.

Essentially I have the id's of the images the user wishes to embed but I don't know how to store each one as a related item.

Comment: Is this question helpful? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/image-not-published-in-data-source-item-sitecore-8-1

Comment: Thanks Marek - looks like I can use a snippet from one of the answers https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2738/3907

Comment: Excellent. I suggest you close your question