# Sitecore smart publish with related items publishes items or not?

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing, related-items

I have been reading about media items publishing where in my scenario I am using Smart publish. I needed to check if this accounts for the Related media items or not as One article says it's included:
[What does the "Publish related items" checkbox do in Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/what-does-the-publish-related-items-checkbox-do-in-sitecore)

while the other says , it's treated as a separate item:

https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/FAQ/Media/Publish%20related%20media%20items.html

What's the actual scenario ?

Regards,
Samridhi

Comment: Your second link points to sdn archive. That's documentation from a very very very old Sitecore versions. There wasn't related items publishing at that time OOTB. Dmytro answer from your first link is correct for modern Sitecore version ( https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1618/277 ).

Comment: I am using SItecore 9.0.2 . The image is for a product where both image as well as  product come from Hybris and this is placed under a Sitecore Bucket . Will that  have any different scenario ?